# Get & update the form data in react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using React & Apollo client to fetch the data from GraphQL server.
Now I have written following component in react.

1. Component for listing all the item - working.
2. Component for creating an item - working.
3. Component for updating the item - not working (not sure how to do that).

I have 2 component files.

1. UpdateAudio.js.
2. AudioForm.js.

Now.

1. I need to get the data from GraphQL server for given audioID (will get from the path params).
2. then set that audio in state.
3. and pass the audio state to AudioForm component.

I'm initializing the audio with blank fields initially in state.
I can get the data using Query but I'm not sure how to update the audio state which will be passed to AudioForm and populated the data further.

UpdateAudio.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Mutation, Query, graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { UpdateAudioQuery, GetAudio } from '../query';
import { Button, Grid, LinearProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
import AudioForm from '../components/AudioForm';


class UpdateAudio extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            site: "5d517862-0630-431c-94b1-bf34de6bfd8b",
            audio: {
            site: "5d517862-0630-431c-94b1-bf34de6bfd8b",
            title: '',
            description: '',

            }
        };
        this.updateCache = this.updateCache.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    updateCache = (cache, { data }) => {
        if (data.createAudio.audio.guid) {
            console.log("redirecting...")
            this.props.history.push('/audios')
        }
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            audio: {
            ...prevState['audio'],
            [name]: value,
            }
        }));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <AudioForm audio={this.state.audio} handleChange={this.handleChange}  />
                <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center">
                    <Grid item>
                        <Mutation mutation={UpdateAudioQuery} update={this.updateCache}>
                            {(Update, {loading, data, error}) => {
                            if (loading) {
                                return <Button variant="contained" size="large" color="secondary" disabled>Save</Button>
                            }
                            else if (error) {
                                return <div>{error}</div>
                            }
                            else {
                                return <Button variant="contained" size="large" color="secondary" onClick={() => Update({variables: this.state.audio})}>Update</Button>
                            }
                            }}
                        </Mutation>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

UpdateAudio = withRouter(UpdateAudio)

export default graphql(GetAudio,
    {
        name:'Get',
        options: ownProps => ({ variables: {site: "5d517862-0630-431c-94b1-bf34de6bfd8b", guid: ownProps.match.params.guid} })
    })(UpdateAudio);
```

AudioForm.js

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import { TextField, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';


class AudioForm extends React.Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.audio.title);

    return (
      <Fragment>
      <form  noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <Grid container spacing={24} alignItems="center" justify="center">
          <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
            <TextField
              id="audio-title"
              name="title"
              label="Title"
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              fullWidth
              defaultValue={this.props.audio.title}
              onChange={this.props.handleChange}
              required
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
            <TextField
              id="audio-description"
              name="description"
              label="Description"
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              fullWidth
              defaultValue={this.props.audio.description}
              onChange={this.props.handleChange}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </form>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}


export default AudioForm;
```

query.js

```
    import gql from 'graphql-tag';


    export const GetAudio = gql`
        query Get($site: String!, $guid: String!) {
        getAudio(site: $site, guid: $guid){
            guid
            siteGuid
            title
            description
        }
    }`

    export const UpdateAudio = gql`
        mutation Update($site: String!, $guid: String!, $title: String, $description: String) {
        updateAudio(
            input:{
                guid: $guid,
                site: $site,
                title: $title,
                description: $description
            }
        ) {
            audio{
                guid
                siteGuid
                title
                status
            }
        }
    }`;
```

Comment: Are you possible to do the update through the GraphQl playground? does it throw an error?

Comment: Yes update works with the GraphQL playground. I'm not facing issue with graphql. Issue is how I can fetch the data for existing ID and fill the form in react and then send the updated content back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i got your question. 
Just do query like like below. Do not use render props method for query because you cant do setState there.

Best place for below method is getDerivedStateFromProps function.
Do this work there.

```
client.query({
    query: GetAudio,
    variables: { site, guid }
  })
  .then((res) => {
    // check for response and do setState
    // example ... 
    const { site, title, description } = res;
    this.setState({ site, title, description });
  })
.catch( err => console.log(err));
```

Also check the link from official docs 
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#manual-query

I read i think more than 5 times your question if i got this wrong forgive me.

Stay blessed.

Comment: Is client.query going to work? As per documenation we can access client using <ApolloConsumer> but this expect to return something. We cannot just set the state inside the it. It's gives this error:
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: Never mind. I can use withApollo and access the client directly. Now I can set the audio data which I get from the API.

Comment: @ShashankSachan, I am still facing issue with Update forms would you please send me complete form example?
Thanks